# Linking with 3rd party library causes segfault in openssl

Tags: c++, qt, openssl, segmentation-fault

I have a 3rd party library that's using OpenSSL, also I'm using Qt networking classes for accessing a service that's running on https.

What's puzzling is that when I link with my application with a proprietary library then it segfaults during a call to QSslSocket, in code belonging to OpenSSL. All I have to do to get the segfault is to link with it, without calling any functions from the library.
When I don't link with the library then everything works fine.

The segfault looks like this

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:209
209     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcmp.S:209
#1  0x00007ffff72a4a5a in getrn () from /usr/lib64/libs63lib-5.16-dynr.so.10.0
#2  0x00007ffff72a4d90 in lh_insert () from /usr/lib64/libs63lib-5.16-dynr.so.10.0
#3  0x00007ffff72391fc in OBJ_NAME_add () from /usr/lib64/libs63lib-5.16-dynr.so.10.0
#4  0x00007ffff41ddba8 in SSL_library_init () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
#5  0x00007ffff6b14b12 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#6  0x00007ffff6b16de9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#7  0x00007ffff6b050b9 in QSslCertificate::QSslCertificate(QByteArray const&, QSsl::EncodingFormat) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#8  0x00007ffff6b0f429 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#9  0x00007ffff6b1760e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#10 0x00007ffff6b1230f in QSslSocket::QSslSocket(QObject*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
#11 0x0000000000404438 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdb98) at s63seg.cpp:49
```

Here are the last lines from strace.

```
close(4)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbab8e95000, 110592, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fbabc672000, 215488)          = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=215488, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 215488, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7fbabc672000
close(4)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20.\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=382984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2478288, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x7fbab8887000
mprotect(0x7fbab88db000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbab8adb000, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0x54000) = 0x7fbab8adb000
mmap(0x7fbab8ae4000, 208, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbab8ae4000
close(4)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbab8adb000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fbabc672000, 215488)          = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---
```

Any idea what might be causing it or how I could prevent it?
When anything else fails then I could just put the code that uses the proprietary library in a separate executable and call it with system() or something similar, but that wouldn't be a very nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two uses of OpenSSL are conflicting. You can only have one implementation of `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback()`, `CRYPTO_set_id`, and the other callback functions. Two users of OpenSSL in the same process have to cooperate on these things.

Comment: How should different libraries that don't know anything about eachother do that? I guess that I as an end-user can't do anything about it?

Comment: @TõnisM Not much you can do. This is one of the many WTF's in OpenSSL.

Comment: @David - forgive my ignorance. How did you diagnose the issue? I would have guessed `QSslSocket` was using a version of OpenSSL that's binary incompatible with what's being provided by the system. I'd like to see the output of `ldd` on QT (to see what OpenSSL version QT was built against), and see the output of `info shared` under the debugger (to see what OpenSSL version was actually loaded).

Comment: @Jww The diagnosis comes from the position of the stack fault. But your guess overlaps mine.